# parameter operation inside awk line

Tags: awk, variable, parameter

When I run `bjobs -w` in the machine where I work, I get the next output:

```
JOBID   USER  STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME SUBMIT_TIME
821213  user1 RUN   parallel16 hpc2        16*pirineus NAME1111 Apr 9 20:26
823954  user1 RUN   parallel16 hpc1        5*pirineus4 NAME2222 Apr 11 22:45
824083  user1 RUN   parallel16 hpc1        16*collserola2 otherthing Apr 12 19:20
824297  user1 RUN   parallel16 hpc1        8*collserola10 another_long_name Apr 13 20:50
824305  user1 RUN   parallel16 hpc2        16*collserola5 Try_anothername Apr 14 12:16
```

Then, I want to get the information from the first and sixth column. For that, I thought I could do it like this

```
bjobs |awk '(NR>=2) {print $1 " "$6 }'
```

but then, I am getting

```
821213 16*pirineus
823954 5*pirineus
824083 16*collsero
824297 8*collsero
824305 16*collsero
```

when I would like to get

```
821213 pirineus
823954 pirineus4
824083 collsero2
824297 collsero10
824305 collsero5
```

I tried the next command (following the idea of using parameter operations) but it gave me an error.

```
bjobs |awk '(NR>=2) {print $1" " ${6#* *} }'

awk: (NR>=2) {print $1" " ${6#* *} }
awk:                       ^ syntax error
awk: línea ord.:1: (NR>=2) {print $1" " ${6#* *} }
awk: línea ord.:1:                         ^ syntax error
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Comment: Why would `awk` treat `16*pirineus` as two fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the shell's parameter substitution inside an `awk` program.

To strip out the first bit of the sixth column, use `sub()`:

```
bjobs -w | awk 'NR > 1 { sub("^[^*]*[*]", "", $6); print $1, $6 }'
```

This would modify the sixth field by removing the bit up to the `*` before printing it.  The regular expression `^[^*]*[*]` matches any number of characters that are not `*` at the beginning of the string, and then the `*`.  This is then replaced by the empty string.

The above transforms the output in the question to

```
821213 pirineus
823954 pirineus4
824083 collserola2
824297 collserola10
824305 collserola5
```

NOTE: *All variations below (including the `sed` solution) assumes that there is a `*` in the sixth field*. The above would work even if there wasn't.

Another way of doing it is to split the sixth field on the `*` and print the second part:

```
bjobs -w | awk 'NR > 1 { split($6, a, "[*]"); print $1, a[2] }'
```

A third way of doing it is using both blanks and `*` as the field delimiter (note the change in field number):

```
bjobs -w | awk -F "[[:blank:]*]+" 'NR > 1 { print $1, $7 }'
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
bjobs -w | sed -nE 's/^([[:alnum:]]+).*\*([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: In all  option the Sufix number of column 6 (e.g. collsero**10** , pirineus**4**, ... ) is missing. Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: @Seven77 Um, they're not missing when I run with the data that you posted. I never touch that part of the string.

Comment: @Seven77 Hmm... could it be that your output is from `bjobs -w` (first line of the question), but that you then use `bjobs` (no `-w`)?  I was using the output that you posted, and if that's from `bjobs -w` then you should use `bjobs -w` with my solutions too.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I used bjobs instead of bjobs -w. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I  have used below command to get the desired output

```
awk 'NR >=2{print $1,$6}' example.txt  | sed "s/[0-9]\{1,2\}\*//g"
```

output

```
821213 pirineus
823954 pirineus4
824083 collserola2
824297 collserola10
824305 collserola5
```